# Magento 1.9.3.2 - Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, security, session

I have just moved a Magento install from one server to another and now when I try to access the frontend I get the "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons" error.

I have already tried the following, but none work:

1. Added reference to tmp folder magento_directory/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php
   and also created the folder in the root directory.
2. Delete everything is cache and session folders.

The output from the error report is below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php:225 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(188): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnectionTypeInstance('{{db_type}}') 
#1 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('{{db_type}}', Array) 
#2 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_setup') 
#3 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup') 
#4 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates() 
#5 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() 
#6 /home/samplesite/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App in /home/samplesite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 225
```

Could anyone help with understanding the issue and possible solutions please?

Comment: Just to clarify, database credentials in local.xml are accurate.

Comment: Check in your local.xml there is no space or line breaks around the values.

Answer (score 4):

1. Navigate to the "errors" folder.
2. Change **local.xml.sample** to **local.xml**
3. You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay
4. Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:
   protected $_options = array(
   'cache_dir' => 'null',
5. Change it to:
   protected $_options = array(
   'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
6. Save it.
7. Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
   That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your response but as you can see in my question, point 1, I have already done that.

Comment: Have you try this also - Change local.xml.sample to local.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's about line :

```
$this->_connectionTypes[$type] = new $typeClass();
```

So same like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377491/magento-fatal-error-class-name-must-be-a-valid-object-or-a-string)

Check lines in local.xml do you have any spaces between lines and check in connection tags do you have :

```
<type>pdo_mysql</type>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. There are no spaces and yes I have <type>pdo_mysql</type> in the connection tag

Answer (score 0):

/errors/report.php
Do
print_r($reportData)